# what is the best way to draw automata using the mouse?

Tags: graph, drawing, finite-automata

I need a efficient way the draw some finite automata , I tried using word shapes but it very exhausting. I looking for another way to do that only by mouse drawing (not java extant like [jgraph](http://www.jgraph.com/) or [graphviz](http://graphviz.org/)).

**EDIT :**

Since no one answered me , after some tests I think that best way to draw simple automata is using power point .

Comment: I like Inkscape for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want alternatives for windows the famous one is [xfig](http://xfig.org/). There is also [IPE](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/). The hardcore automators use [gastex](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~gastin/gastex/).